# Can you return the single string data from room database?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

I have made have a model with **8** types of fields  and i want to get the **single** item from the **row**  using room Database.

For example :

If i have a table named **ABC** in which i have Following things are as Columns( **id , Unique_ID , PAR1 , PAR2 , PAR3 and so on ..**) with  one column name **Unique_ID** then what i want is to query the Column name **UNIQUE_ID**  with **x** data  then  i should be able to return the string that is present in **PAR2** column  .

Somehow you cannot return the string of data in **DAO**.

What can i do to get only **single string data** ?

Comment: @Query("SELECT PAR2 FROM ABC WHERE UNIQUE_ID = :id")                             fun getPAR2(id: Int) : List<String>                                                                                      isn't this working?

Comment: Getting this error . The query returns some columns [id,Unique_ID, par1,par2] which are not use by java.lang.String. You can use @ColumnInfo annotation on the fields to specify the mapping.

Comment: Have tried `@Query("select part2 from ABC where uniqe_id in (:xArray)")` for your query?

Comment: Thank you guys . what i did is added @Query("select part2 from ABC where uniqe_id in (:xArray)") with String getSingleData(int unique_id); Now its showing the data ..